# "This element is causing an element to overflow," how to find "an element" in this problem?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to web development and got this weird error message.

How shall I find "...an element..." as per error message? FF Dev tool doesn't show any flag as well.

`"This element.." = <footer class="footer-grid">` right ?

[image]

Comment: Was the message in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This element is causing an element to overflow in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556531/this-element-is-causing-an-element-to-overflow-in-firefox)

Comment: Not on the console but FF dev tooltip. I've checked the SO query but it doesn't say how to find problematic element, it says how to fix it. My question is different one.

Comment: Well, visually, I guess? Try viewing it without device preview and see what popups. Sorry, I don't use FF.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS - it will add a red border around every element so you can see what might be causing an issue.

```
 * {border:1px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be a problem with firefox itself.

I'm using firefox + devtools and have an html document which shows a simple CSS grid.

When I expand the devtools panel up so that it hides part of the grid then the overflow badges start to appear against html elements which are now hidden by the devtools panel.

I'm running firefox 104.0(64 bit) on a Windows 10 PC.